# Scanf two numbers at a time from stdout

Tags: c, scanf, scanning

I have a program that outputs a huge array of integers to stdout, each integer in a line. Ex:

```
103
104
105
107
```

I need to write another program that reads in that array and fill up the spaces where the number isn't an increment of 1 of the previous number. The only different between numbers is going to be 2 (105,107), which makes it easier.

This is my code to do that logic:

```
printf("d",num1);

if ((num2-num1) != 1)
    numbetween =  num1 + 1;
    printf("%d", numbetween);
    printf("%d", num2);
else(
    printf("%d",num2);
)
```

So the output of this program will now be:

```
103
104
105
106
107
```

My issue is reading the numbers. I know I can do `while (scanf("%hd", &num) != EOF)` to read all the lines one at a time. But to do the logic that I want, I'm going to need to read two lines at a time and do computation with them, and I don't know how.

Comment: How about doing two `scanf()` calls on each loop iteration?

Comment: You don't have to read two numbers on each iteration. You *start* by reading two numbers. After that the algorithm only reads one number at a time, promoting whatever the prior iteration's `num2` was to be `num1` first, refilling `num2` from stdin, etc.. Finish by outputing `num2`.

Comment: @WhozCraig I was being an idiot. There's a much simplier way of doing this. Grab the first number in the file, grab the last number, loop starting at the first number until you reach the last number and output your loop counter each time. But the question now is, how do I grab the first and last numbers from stdout ?

Comment: The first number is easy; you read it.  The last number is also easy; you remember the last number you read, and keep reading new numbers until the input fails, updating the last one read when you get a new number.

Comment: ...and make sure you did, in fact, read at least *two* numbers. A file with only one number should be considered an error state or a range of one. up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You could always just read the first and last numbers from the file, and then print everything in between.

```
int main( void )
{
    // get the first value in the file
    int start;
    if ( scanf( "%d", &start ) != 1 )
        exit( 1 );

    // get the last value in the file
    int end = start;
    while ( scanf( "%d", &end ) == 1 )
        ;

    // print the list of numbers
    for ( int i = start; i <= end; i++ )
        printf( "%d\n", i );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read first `num` then add missing if needed when you read next `int`

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                             
#include <stdlib.h>                                                            

int main()                                                                     
{                                                                              
    int previous = 0;                                                          
    int num;                                                                   
    scanf("%hd", &previous);                                                   

    while (scanf("%hd", &num) != EOF) {                                        
        for (int i = previous; i < num; i++) {                                 
            printf("%d\n" , i);                                                
        }                                                                      
        previous = num;                                                        
    }                                                                          
    printf("%d\n" , previous);                                                 

    return 0;                                                                  
}
```

this input

```
100
102
103
105
107
110
```

returns this output

```
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can read the `first` and `last`, to fill the range, what you are really doing is finding the `min` and `max` and printing all values between them inclusively. Below the names are left `first` and `last`, but they represent `min` and `max` and will cover your range regardless whether the values are entered in order. Taking that into consideration, another approach insuring you cover the limits of the range of `int` would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int num = 0;
    int first = (1U << 31) - 1;  /* INT_MAX */
    int last = (-first - 1);     /* INT_MIN */

    /* read all values saving only first (min) and last (max) */        
    while (scanf (" %d", &num) != EOF) {
        first = num < first ? num : first;
        last = num > last ? num : last;
    }

    /* print all values first -> last */        
    for (num = first; num <= last; num++)
        printf ("%d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/firstlast.txt
21
25
29
33
37
41
45
49
53
57
61
65
69
73
77
81
85
89
93
97
101
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/firstlast < dat/firstlast.txt
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
<snip>
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
101
```

**Note:** you can change the `types` to conform to your expected range of data.